# SAPUI5 Table Items Duplicate IDs

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a SAPUI5 application where you first choose a object and then a new table is build up which is showing some data to this selected object. I am creating list items with some input fields with unique ids. If a user goes back to select a new object, the table is built new the same way but has erros because it tries to create new ids which are already in use (duplicate ids) Is there a way in SAPUI5 to delete this ids or destroy the items? I tried it with table.destroyItems() and table.destroy() but i had no success. Did somebody of you already faced a problem like this?

Comment: Why do you need unique IDs for input fields?

Comment: Its because of value help dialogs. I am opening from every input a dialog and i am making own ids because there is a paramter which i need. Its not solved perfectly

Comment: Then try to solve that. There is no need for input IDs

Comment: Not using static IDs would "hide" the problem at best. Could you please share relevant parts of your model / view / controller code.

Comment: I solved the problem. I am not using static IDs anymore. The parameter which i passed trough the IDs is now passing by Custom Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I am not using static IDs anymore. The parameter which i passed trough the IDs is now passing by Custom Data

Answer (score 0):

Set data of model as empty array as per your requirement,

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  oModel.setData({results: []});
```

OR

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  oModel.setData([]);
```

Comment: I solved the problem. I am not using static IDs anymore. The parameter which i passed trough the IDs is now passing by Custom Data